# codeigniter new helper is not load

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try load custom helper but it is not load and generate error like this

> An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: helpers/getdata_helper.php

my helper is stored in

> Application/helper/getdata.php

my controller is

```js
class home extends CI_Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('url','form','language','string'));  
      $this->load->helper('getdata');
        //$this->EE->load->helper('menu_load'); 
    }   
    public function index()
    {   
        $menu['menu']=$this->home_model->get_menu();         
        $menu['print_menu']=$this->echoMenu($menu['menu']);

        $data['latest']=$this->home_model->get_latest_product();    
        $this->load->view('header_1',$menu);
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Comment: Your helper file name should be `Application/helper/getdata_helper.php`.

Comment: I agree with the comment above.. in addition, you don't need to load getdata by itself, you can place it in the array where you're loading all the other helpers. Also, if you are planning to use these helpers all over your site you might want to consider autoloading them in `application\config\autoload.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what des [doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html) says :

> Loading a helper file is quite simple using the following function:
>   $this->load->helper('name');
>
> Where name is the file name of the helper, without the .php file
>   extension or the "helper" part.
>
> For example, to load the URL Helper file, which is named
>   url_helper.php, you would do this: $this->load->helper('url');

It clearly suggests that CI will look for a file named xxx_helper.php. 
In you case, when load `getdata`, CI will look for `getdata_helper.php` inside `application/helpers` .

You just have to rename your file to make it work.

Comment: I agree, This should be the culprit.

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't give a error. Anyways try to auto load it like:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('getdata');
```